# Wordpress Form Processing

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, action

I have created a form on my wordpress site, a function to process the data located in functions.php, and an action php file. I have tested the processing function and know it works, but I'm having trouble getting everything to communicate with wordpress.

update_item_meta.php is located in my theme directory.

**Form Opening Tag**

```
<form method="post" id="project-info" action="/wp-content/themes/Avada/update_item_meta.php">
```

**update_item_meta.php**

```
<?php
//connect to WP
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-load.php');

//call function from functions.php to process form data
update_item_meta_data();
?>
```

Note: wp-load.php is located in the main site root

If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it. If i had to guess it's a problem with either the path to update_item_meta.php in the form action or update_item_meta.php, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: `If i had to guess it's a problem with either the path to update_item_meta.php in the form action or update_item_meta.php`. both  seems are problematic. provide full path in both and check.

Comment: @Anant I believe that is the full path to wp-load.php from inside the Avada  theme directory. I also updated the action above with the full path I tried and it did not work.

Comment: I think if you are going to use this kind of behavior in different sites the best is to define an endpoint using the Wordpress API so you can usa that  without the need of `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` and 
`require('../../../wp-load.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action="/wp-content/themes/Avada/update_item_meta.php"`

You will obviously not load wp calling a php file directly and using relative paths to load wp is problematic.

The best way to deal with forms in wp are to post to the same url:

1. `action="#"` with a hidden input for a unique field to identify your form and in your functions file a function to pick up the post action....

   ```
   if($_POST['unique']){
     require_once 'yourfile.php';
     //or your form process code here
   }
   ```
2. `action="#"` and place code to handle the post in your template file (not the wp way but helps prevent a load of code from being loaded that is not relevant to the page.

Both ways will have wp loaded for you without having to manually load.